# Is it possible to replace Excel's VBA Editor/IDE with a modern alternative?

Tags: excel, vba, ide, editor

Is it possible to replace Excel's built-in VBA Editor or IDE with a modern one such as VS Code or VS Studio?

As a C# developer, I prefer the Visual Studio IDE. Excel's VBA Editor/IDE is very dated by comparison. It lacks the sophisticated features found in even the most basic IDEs, such as column selection, jump to references, and useful keyboard shortcuts. As an example, there's no keyboard shortcut for terminating a debugging session.

While it does support many useful features such as suggestions, syntax checking and syntax coloring, they don't work well. It still lacks anything like intellisense. The syntax checking is very obstructive and limited to the most obvious cases. The syntax coloring is limited to keywords and comments. It's autocompletion only works in limited scenarios.

Comment: .NET (Visual Studio, C#, etc.) was a fresh start for Microsoft into which they poured everything they had learnt from earlier products.  So the VB.NET editor is better than the C# editor is better than any of the VBA editors and I doubt this will change.

Comment: You could just develop for Office in Visual Studio and continue using C#.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut for stopping an Excel debug is "Alt+R+R" (ie. Reset).

Comment: See https://datanitro.com/product for a solution using Python.

Comment: The reasons given for closing this question are not very relevant. The VBA editor is closely integrated with Excel, meaning that it is not trivial to replace it. That is, if any editor can be used to replace it, it would be a positive answer to this question. In such a situation it is hardly a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might consider using VB.NET instead of VBA for your Excel development. [Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) (which I develop) is an open source framework for integrating .NET in Excel, which tries to make the VBA to .NET conversion as easy as possible.

Then you can use any editor for the VB.NET (or C#) code, including the Visual Studio Express editions or [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/).

Comment: When people request a better editor for their language, it's not very appropriate to suggest switching to another language.

Comment: However, if you want to change the editor, you might also want to change the language. This fits well for VBA imho.

Comment: This project would be much better if it worked with all office apps like Outlook, Word and PowerPoint. Being only an Excel tool is a huge limitation.

Comment: The Excel-DNA project has been moved to GitHub and can be found here: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna

Comment: You can strongly improve the default VBA IDE with RubberDuck - see https://rubberduckvba.com/